# How do I fill in missing values using another dataframe based on date condition, but which are different shapes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, fill

I am trying to fill missing num values (scores) by conditionally matching 'date' objects in two datasets. The challenge I am facing is that the datasets are not the same shape. I have 17k rows in the df I am attempting to fill to, but only 1500 in the df I am attempting to fill from and keep receiving the error, "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Obviously I am using the comparison operator '==' and that's where I am going wrong according to the error code, but I can't figure out how to work around that. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
df1['score'] = df1.where(df1.Date == df2.Date, df1['score'].fillna(df2['score'], inplace=True) )
```

df1 looks like:
|Index|Attrib1|Attrib2|Date|
|-----|-------|-------|----|
|0    |  123  | 98    |2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z|
|1    |  456  |  56   |2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z|
|2    | 8901  |456    |2022-01-29T00:00:00.000Z|
|3    | 566   |456    |2022-01-28T00:00:00.000Z|
|4    |  12   |987    |2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z|
|5    | 354   |00     |2022-01-29T00:00:00.000Z|
|6    |  25   |915    |2022-01-28T00:00:00.000Z|

df2 looks like:
|Index|score|Date|
|-----|-----|----|
|0    |  50 |2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z|
|1    |  12 |2022-01-30T00:00:00.000Z|
|2    |  78 |2022-01-29T00:00:00.000Z|
|3    |  25 |2022-01-28T00:00:00.000Z|

Comment: Can you post some expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You first need make the date column the index of each DataFrame, then the fillna should work:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df2 = df2.set_index('Date')

df1['score'].fillna(df2['score'], inplace = True)
```